# Symfony2 templates/layouts

Tags: symfony

I am new to symfony2 so please forgive me if this is a stupid question.

Symfony2 is organised in bundles - so everything is a bindle right?

Based on this I have created the following bundles in order to have a simple login mechanism:

- App

  - The main bundle will contain all global functionality
- User

  - Will be used to represent users

So the bundles work correctly and all is fine.

Now I cant figure out the best way to add a layout/theme structure to the site.

I obviously need some global assets such as header, nav and foooter.  But additionally, there needs to be some global css style sheets, jquery etc.

The most obvious place bundle is App - but how do i make all other bundles inherit the theme from this bundle.  For example, the user bundle template needs to extend the App bundle etc.

The idea for bundles is that they are modular and self contained, therefore how can this be achieved

Comment: You can access any other bundles templates etc, by their bundle name. Think of them like a class, they are contained, but accessible.

Comment: Read the SF2 Book! :) http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/index.html

Answer (score 1):

I personally use like this:

There is MainBundle (in your case, it is App) which does global services, twig extensions and layout. Global assets are included in this file.

Main layout of all the other bundles extends the layout of MainBundle. Templates inside each bundle extend to the main layout of it which extend the layout of MainBundle. For example,

```
- MainBundle
    - views
         - layout.html.twig
- UserBundle
    - views
         - layout.html.twig (extends to MainBundle/layout)
         - show.html.twig (extends to UserBundle/layout)
         - friends.html.twig (extends to UserBundle/layout)
```

Comment: This is what i thought of but it means the UserBundle has to 'know' about MainBundle, in my case App.  So they are now coupled, as will every other bundle i install

Comment: @MartyWallace you're exactly right, since they are completely coupled to your application and you have no reason/intention to separate them, there's no advantage to having them as separate bundles. Check my answer below.

Comment: then you can define your App bundle in config; every other bundle will 'know' about it from configuration parameter. There is nothing you can do beyond that. I know that they are self contained but you must relate each other at one point like some 3rd parties should be configured in config.yml

Answer (score 1):

Everything is explained in the official docs: http://symfony.com/doc/current/templating.html

The basic global view (templates) resources are placed in the following dir:

```
app/Resources/views/index.html.twig
```

If you have a specific purpose, or bundles, templates, place them in the subdirs, e.g.:

```
app/Resources/views/blog/index.html.twig
```

And if you want to keep everything in the bundle (must for reusable code), use this convention:

```
[VendorName/]YourBundle/Resources/views/Blog/index.html.twig
```

(Of course, any name, except the ".html.twig" extension for Twig, may be changed to your liking)

Answer (score 0):

The strategy I prefer is to organize my application in a single bundle. If you have no intention of re-using distinct standalone features across multiple applications then this is the most appropriate way. Having a "UserBundle" in your own application namespace probably doesn't make sense. You're adding a lot of extra structure that's serving you no advantage. Consider this instead:

```
- MainBundle
    - Controller
        - UserController
        - OtherController
    - Resources
        - views
            - layout.html.twig
            - User
                - show.html.twig
                - update.html.twig
                - friends.html.twig
            - Other
                - some_other_view.html.twig
```

In this case the templates under the controller directories would extend `MainBundle::layout.html.twig`.

Comment: What about installing  a 3rd party bundle.  How would this pick up the MainBundle layout?  Would this mean changing the 3rd party bundle code?I think this, in a way, defeats the purpose of bundles.  Like zend has modules, symfony has bundles and this modularized approach has many benefits.  I get your point about reuse, but theres more to this than reuse i think.  A logical seperation of concerns makes sense and makes the code more maintable doesnt it?

Comment: This doesn't stop you from using third-party bundles. There's not a 1-to-1 relationship with third party bundles and your application code. So I'm not exactly sure what you mean.

Comment: This means that you should have one bundle for an application? Why bothering having bundle system?

Comment: Ok, say i introduce a 3rd party bundle to the system.  It has some views for pages.  I obviously want it to pick up the same layout as the other pages on the site.  How can i configure things without having to amend the 3rd party bundles code

Comment: That's sort of the point, there's nothing "above" a bundle. It's just  a way to organize the code so that other parts of Symfony know where to look for things.

Comment: That depends on the third-party bundle. In the case of FOSUserBundle you can override the templates as described here https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/overriding_templates.md

Comment: This is the crux of my question.  Having to change or override bundles to fit in with the site seems like a lot of work

Comment: You only have to change them if you want them to be customized. But it's unlikely a third-party view is going to fit in your sites style seamlessly so this is usually the case. If you have a specific bundle in mind I can try to answer it less generally.

Comment: The bundle system is easy, flexible and provide standard modular approach, and was introduced for a number of reasons. I don't see any advantage in re-inventing modular system, as it's already made, and it's great enough, plus it (i.e. bundles) is supported by framework itself.